# How to design Grids for sudoku in Android

Tags: android, grid, android-canvas, sudoku

I am designing a sudoku game in android.I have tried 81 text views. It shows me, it is a bad idea using 81 text views. I don't know how to use canvas. So can you help to get through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [sample source code](https://github.com/anthonymoralez/hello-android-sudoku) for sudoku from the book hello android.